In Java, why is the following assignment successful?
class A<T>{
}

class B<T extends Integer>{
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        A<B<?>> a1 = null;
        A<B<? extends Integer>> a2 = null;
    
        a1 = a2;
    }    
}

According to my judgment, in this program, the type of a1 is not a supertype of the type of a2.And capture conversion is just an identity conversion for both the types of a1 and a2.
I think a1 = a2; is a conversion chain. According to the content of JLS 5.2:

It is a compile-time error if the chain of conversions contains two
parameterized types that are not in the subtype relation (§4.10)

But my compiler doesn't give any errors or even warnings.
Why is such an assignment allowed?

Because of T extends Integer in B?

According to my judgement (and the compiler's) the type of a1 is a supertype of the type of a2.  Any type that matches ? extends Integer will also match ?.  But the type constraint in A<B<? extends Integer>> is redundant anyway because the same constraint is expressed on T in the class declaration of B.

@StephenC: A type that matches ? extends Integer matches ?, but that isn't enough to make A<B<? extends Integer>> compatible with A<B<?>>. Take out the extends Integer in T extends Integer, and this program won't compile.

This is similar to how Integer is assignable to Object, but List<Integer> isn't assignable to List<Object>.

"Take out the extends Integer in T extends Integer, and this program won't compile." - So maybe that's the reason.  The constraint on T makes the constraint on ? redundant.

@StephenC: Yes, as correctly pointed out by talex. ? extends Integer matching ? is unrelated to what's going on.

@Stephen C According to the JLS 4.10.2, I can't determine that the type of a1 is a supertype of the type of a2. The type ofa1 doesn't contain the type of a2.May I ask how you reached this conclusion?

@user2357112 How should I judge that the type of a1 is a supertype of the type of a2?
According to the JLS 4.10.2, I can't determine that the type of a1 is a supertype of the type of a2. The type of a1 doesn't contain the type of a2.

@talex moved to Codidact As you said, T extends Integer, that's correct. However, I think there is no subtype relationship between A<B<?>> and A<B<? extends Integer>> (according to JLS 4.10.2, there is no “containment” relationship between the two types). Then, according to the specification, this would be an error.

A<B<?>> a1 is compatible with A<B<? extends Integer>> a2 as you declared class B<T extends Integer>.

@DuncG Well, I know that they are compatible, as demonstrated by my compiler. However, I want to know which rule in the specification can prove that they are compatible (for example, there is a subtype relationship between the two). At least I can't find such a rule for now.

My point is both variables can be assigned to each other a1 = a2;  a2=a1; because of the way you have declared B
